# Dynamic Allocation For A 2D Array Results in Memory Leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, valgrind, realloc

I am implementing a 2D Matrix with 2 columns for each row, for storing data came from a text file, which I don't know the number of lines. Because I dont know the size, I am trying to reallocate whenever it's needed by the following implementation.

```
typedef struct {
    int **array;
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
} Array;

void initArray(Array *a, size_t initialSize) {
    a-> array = (int **)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < initialSize; i++)
    {
        a->array[i] = (int *) malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    }
    a->used = 0;
    a->size = initialSize;
}
void insertArray(Array *a, int firstValue, int secondValue) {

    if (a->used == a->size) {
        a->size *= 2;
        *a->array = (int *) realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(int));
        for (int i = a->used; i < a->size; i++)
        {
            a->array[i] = (int *) malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
        }
    }
    a->array[a->used][0] = firstValue;
    a->array[a->used][1] = secondValue;
    a->used++;
}
void freeArray(Array *a)
{
    for(int i=0; i < a->size; i++)
    {
        free(a->array[i]);
    }
    free(a->array);
    *a->array = NULL;
    a->used = 0;
    a->size = 0;
}
//For easy debugging I added a dummy main
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Array array;
    initArray(&array, 5);
    for(int i=0; i<123; i++)
    {
        insertArray(&array, i, i+1);
    }
    freeArray(&array);
}
```

So my aim is clearly to expand the array by allocating 1x more memory whenever its needed. But there are errors in my implementations that I can't find.

1-) I create an array, and fill it with less than **initialSIze** , and free it using the function. It looks fine, but if i check with valgrind, I get the following issue, but it says no memory leak:

```
==11887== Invalid write of size 8
==11887==    at 0x109449: freeArray (in /home/qweqwe/CLionProjects/untitled/main)
==11887==    by 0x1095DE: main (in /home/qweqwe/CLionProjects/untitled/main)
==11887==  Address 0x4a4e260 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
==11887==    at 0x483CA3F: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11887==    by 0x109441: freeArray (in /home/qweqwe/CLionProjects/untitled/main)
==11887==    by 0x1095DE: main (in /home/qweqwe/CLionProjects/untitled/main)
==11887==  Block was alloc'd at
==11887==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11887==    by 0x10926D: initArray (in /home/qweqwe/CLionProjects/untitled/main)
==11887==    by 0x109505: main (in /home/qweqwe/CLionProjects/untitled/main)
```

2-) When I try to add one more than **initialSize**, the first pair of elements (array->array[0][0], array->array[0][1]) are replaced with some random numbers, (I am freeing them by mistake?). And when I do a valgrind check, returns a ton of error messages including a memory leak. If I add even more, I got this error:

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So whats the issue there? I am allocating memory wrong somehow? Then how should i do it?

P.S: My first question is solved with removing the * from a->array = NULL; at freeArray function. Please help me with second issue...

Comment: `*a->array = NULL;` = bad mojo there. Just saying. You probably wanted `a->array = NULL;`

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah, chaning that to a->array = null; solved the first problem, thanks!

Comment: See anything similar in that resize? `*a->array = (int *) realloc(...` is what I'm referring to. I don't know why you're tunneling on applying that deref operator in both of those cases. The latter should be `a->array = realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(int*));`. And the one in the embedded for-loop should be using `sizeof(int)`, not `sizeof(int*)`

Comment: @WhozCraig yes.., I am ashamed now.. lol